# How to properly format this object

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, forms, object

i got an object with arrays that gives this output (the input is from a series of forms with group-names) :

```
{ 
  username: [ 'username1', 'username2' ],
  firstname: [ 'firstname1', 'firstname2' ],
  lastname: [ 'lastname1', 'lastname2' ],
  email: [ 'email1', 'email2' ],
 }
```

And I want the object to be formatted like this :

```
  [{username : username1,
    firstname : firstname1,
    lastname : lastname1,
    email : email1},

    {username: username2,
     firstname: firstname2,
     lastname : lastname2,
     email : email2}
                       ]
```

As i'm using node.js, i think there is some method with lodash. Can anyone give me some help? Thank You !

Comment: Does each array have the same length ?

Comment: yes, as it is taken from a series of user input with required infos for each form-group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible solution, using `Array#forEach` and `Object.keys`.

```js
var obj = { username: [ 'username1', 'username2' ], firstname: [ 'firstname1', 'firstname2' ], lastname: [ 'lastname1', 'lastname2' ], email: [ 'email1', 'email2' ] }, res = [];
 
    obj.username.forEach(function(_, i) {
      var object = {};
      Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(c) {
        object[c] = obj[c][i];
      });
      res.push(object);
    });

    console.log(res);
```

`Array#reduce` option.

```js
var obj = { username: [ 'username1', 'username2' ], firstname: [ 'firstname1', 'firstname2' ], lastname: [ 'lastname1', 'lastname2' ], email: [ 'email1', 'email2' ] },
 
    res = obj.username.reduce(function(s,a,i) {
      var object = {};
      Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(c) {
        object[c] = obj[c][i];
      });
      s.push(object);
      return s;
    }, []);

    console.log(res);
```

Comment: This one is perfect !! Thank you, it solved my problem : )

Answer (score 1):

In plain javascript:

```
var oldObj = { 
  username: [ 'username1', 'username2' ],
  firstname: [ 'firstname1', 'firstname2' ],
  lastname: [ 'lastname1', 'lastname2' ],
  email: [ 'email1', 'email2' ],
};
var newArray =[];
for(var key in oldObj)
{
  oldObj[key].forEach(function(property){
    var index = oldObj[key].indexOf(property);
    if(!newArray[index])
    newArray[index] = {};
    newArray[index][key] = property
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `lodash` -

```
console.log(_.transform(myObj, function(result, value, key) {
  _.each(value, function( val, i){
        if(!result[i]) result[i] = {};
            result[i][key]= val;
        });
}, []));
```

Try it here - [lodash unwind](https://runkit.com/anshulk/lodash-unwind)